# How can I merge two edges in 90 degrees to a one single rounded edge?

Tags: edges

I have the following problem and I do not know how to solve.

I have two edges I would like to merge them with a curve but I do not know how to do it. Here is an example :

[image: Example]
In yellow I marked what I want to achieve with the selected edges.

How can I do  this ?

Thanks !

Comment: I don't think you want to *merge* these edges. In order the geometry to be smoother it should be created somehow (via Subsurf, subdividing, whatever). The solution might depend on how do you want the result to be like, i.e. should remaining edges connect top left corner of yellow part ? Or not only it ? Should all the model be smooth or only these edges ?

Comment: Aside from that you can use very easy workaround - create Bezier curve (or not Bezier), convert it to mesh, join it with main surface and (optionally) connect vertices of curve with ones of mesh. The original edges may be not needed any more,

Comment: If this is an extrusion select the edge that is common between these two running in the Y-Direction, You can hit Ctrl+B and move your mouse away the specified amount, or enter the distance, then you could roll your mouse wheel, or enter the number of segments.